# Python - Is there a built-in function that creates a list of numbers, given the min, the max and the step?

Tags: python, list

What I'm looking for is something doing exactly what "range" does, but with the maximum value at the end of the list. Does such a function exist? It is of course very easy to do it without any built-in function:

```
my_list = range(min_val,max_val,step_val)
my_list.append(max_val)
```

Or:

```
my_list = [val for val in range(min_val,max_val+1,step_val) if val <= max_val]
```

But I'd prefer to use a built-in function for a better code readibility.

Comment: No, there is no additional built-in function, because it is trivial to set the end value to `max_val + step` if you need the end value included: `def range_inclusive(start, stop, step): return range(start, stop + step, step)`.

Comment: is this what you want `range(min_val,max_val+step_val,step_val)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no additional built-in function. It is trivial to set the end value to `max_val + step` if you need the end value included:

```
def range_inclusive(start, stop=None, step=1):
    if stop is None:
        start, stop = 0, start
    return range(start, stop + step, step)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
range(min_val,max_val + step_val, step_val)
```